# Redirecting the user requests with apache mod-rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rules to redirect everything to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Now I need to modify it to support the following
When user tries to access domain.tld redirect him to www.domain.tld
When user tries to access domain.tld/key/... redirect him (permanent redirect) to key.domain.tld/...

Of course I still need to redirect all traffic to the index.php except for when user tries to access css, javascript and images where I need to serve them directly

domain.tld/css/...
subdomain.domain.tld/css/... apache should directly serve the url (css files)
Similarly I need to add js and images folders

I am awful with Apache ReWrite module so PLEASE help me out here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #if a file, css, js, jpg whatever file
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #if thats a directory

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /someprofile.php?username=%2 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This gives me a 500 server error except for www.domain.tld :(
I've searched all logs and also tried 
`RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"` but it doesn't seem to generate anything.
Any ideas?

Comment: try now, I updated it.. do you want to move user from like domain.com/username to username.domain.com ?

didnt really got you. what are you trying to do?

Comment: So, one thing at a time, I want to
  1. add the www subdomain when no subdomain is present
  `domain.com/..anything..  =>  www.domain.com/..anything..`
  2. grab the specific word "key" when present and is first component and add it as subdomain and extend everything else after the domain
  `domain.com/key/..anything.. => key.domain.com/..anything..` marking this also as a permanent redirect.